# Jenkins Build always fails even though it should be unstable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

So I have a jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {
        maven 'Maven 3.3.9'
        jdk 'Oracle JDK 8_181'
    }

    options {
        timestamps()
        timeout(time: 4, unit: 'HOURS')
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/15 5-23 * * 1-5')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Info') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo "Paths:"
                    echo "PATH = ${PATH}"
                    echo "M2_HOME = ${M2_HOME}"
                    echo "\n\nMaven Version:"
                    mvn -v
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    mvn clean compile -X -PJenkinsITSV
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Testing') {
            parallel {
                stage("Tests & Archiving") {
                    stages {
                        stage('Tests') {
                            steps {
                                catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                                    sh '''
                                        exit 1
                                    '''
                                        //mvn test -X --fail-never
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        stage('Archiving') {
                            steps {
                                catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                                    echo "POST TEST"
                                    //archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true
                                    //archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.ear', fingerprint: true
                                    //archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.ejb', fingerprint: true
                                    //archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.war', fingerprint: true
                                    //archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/target/*.zip', fingerprint: true
                                    //junit '**/target/reports/**/*.xml'
                                    //junit '**/target/surefire-reports/*.xml'
                                    //junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("Install") {
                    steps {
                        sh '''
                            mvn install -X -DskipTests=true
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
post {
    failure {
        when { branch 'master' }
        steps {
            echo "Failed"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have commented out some code.

Every step is green, except for the `Tests` stage, where I do `exit 1` (for testing). This step is shown as `UNSTABLE` (yellow) in the Ocean UI.

The problem is, that I want the outcome to also be `UNSTABLE`, but it actually is `FAILED` (red) in both Ocean UI and Default UI.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

If you need more info, leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong place. The failure is coming not from your stages but the `post` block. It must be a part of the `pipeline` block `pipeline {stages{...}post{...}}` rather than after it.